# Javascript - Sort Array of Strings by string index property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hi I'm not sure if I have explained the question properly through the title but I have an Array of Strings as such:

```
["item2:apple", "item0:raddish", "item1:orange"]
```

I would like to sort this Array by the "item`x`" value in the strings.

So the end result would be as such:

```
["item0:raddish", "item1:orange", "item2:apple"]
```

I'm unable to do so with the standard `Array.sort();`

Could I get some help please, thanks!

Comment: `array.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}))`